# 4.3l V6 chevy head bolt placement for long and short bolts

Tags: cylinder-head, bolts

Putting back together my chevy silverado 2001 4.3l V6 after head gasket replacement and I don't remember where the 2 short bolts go in the head. I find plenty of info on the torque specs and tightening order but not which bolts go into which holes

Answer (score 1):

In this video on YouTube, the guy is just pointing out that there are 2 shorter bolts, one at the front and one at the back of the cylinder head (just noticed however, this looks like it is a V8 engine) -

https://youtu.be/X283ckSFMJQ?t=1220

[image]

In these 2 scenes he is showing the locations of the bolts -

[image]

[image]